# How to execute query using Cloudant Java api?

Tags: java, cloudant

From the Cloudant web ui I can execute the following query off my indexes :

```
<>/authoring-test/_design/surveys/_search/multiSearch?q=survey_type%3A%22template%22%20and%20visibility%3A%22public%22
```

But I am unable to access the same query using the java-cloudant api.
My code is as follows :

```
Search search = db.search("_design/surveys/_search/multiSearch");
        log.info("Retrieved search object");
        surveys = search.limit(limit)
                .includeDocs(false)
                .query("survey_type:template", Survey.class);
```

but it throws a `DocumentNotFound` exception.

Does anyone have any pointers on how to execute a query using the cloudant java api?

Comment: improved formatting a tiny bit

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

```
Search search = db.search("search/multiSearch");
log.info("Retrieved search object");
surveys = search.limit(limit)
            .includeDocs(true)
            .query("survey_type:template", Survey.class);
```

Basically the error was a combination of includeDoc(false) and incorrect path to design document.

Hope this helps someone!